# Why isnt my container joining an existing network in docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a simple app that i am trying to connect to an existing network which exists, but when i do `docker-compose up` it is just creating a new network for itself without joining the existing network. The existing network I am trying to join is for traefik which is called proxy. All my other services running behind traefik is working fine. I have to manually add mynewapp to the proxy network for it to work. All my other services compose files are also decoupled in individual folders, so I dont think thats it.

I tried defining external and internal values to true and false, but it still creates its own network. If i define a default network along with the proxy network, then it just creates two new networks called mynodeapp_default and mynodeapp_proxy. If i run `docker network inspect proxy`, I dont see mynewapp in it (but I see all my other running services).

The output of my `docker network list` is

```
62eba8d7e127        proxy                 bridge              local
a50cdb97b743        testapp_proxy         bridge              local
```

What am I doing wrong here?

```
version: '3'

services: 
  mynodeapp:
    container_name: mynodeapp
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./:/app/
    networks: 
      - proxy
    labels: 
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.network=proxy

networks: 
  proxy:
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want a container to join an existing network you need to use the [external option](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#external-1):

```
version: '3'

services: 
  mynodeapp:
    container_name: mynodeapp
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./:/app/
    networks: 
      - proxy
    labels: 
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.network=proxy

networks: 
  proxy:
    external: true
```

Comment: Ah. I did try setting external to true, but forgot to rebuild the container.

Answer (score 0):

you can specify like below also,

```
version: "3"

services: 
  mynodeapp:
    container_name: mynodeapp
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./:/app/
    networks: 
      - proxy
    labels: 
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.network=proxy

networks:
  outside:
    external: true
```

You can also specify the name of the network separately from the name used to refer to it within the Compose file:

```
networks:
  outside:
    external:
      name: actual-name-of-network
```

Not supported for version 2 docker-compose files. Use network_mode instead.

name
Added in version 2.1 file format

Set a custom name for this network.

version: "2.4"
networks:
  network1:
    name: my-app-net